# How to focus an element without triggering screen reader

Tags: html, accessibility

I am currently working on a date picker that should be accessible.

If the user is viewing a month calendar, some dates from the previous month will be visible and some from the next month. Once the user clicks on a month outside the current one, the calendar will change to that month and then highlight the clicked day. During this process, the old grid of days is replaced by the new one and the clicked day in the new grid also receives focus. My problem is that screen readers will read the date on click in the old grid, but then once the grid is re-created and the day is focused, it will be read again.

Is this something I can prevent?

Comment: Firstly accessibility goes beyond screen readers so make sure this works with keyboard only etc and for changing things dynamically make sure you use [`aria-region`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Region_role) to announce to the user that something has changed. Combine this with `aria-label` and you can make this a good experience for everyone.

Comment: @Dominik, you mean `aria-live`, not `aria-region` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: I did indeed. Sorry and thanks for the correction.

Comment: I wonder if you can use the stopPropagation() method to handle this. Similar to preventDefault() but stops further propagation after click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice that you're trying to fix a UX issue to make a more pleasant experience for the screen reader user, but hearing something read twice is an extremely minor problem.  If that's the only accessibility issue on your page, then that's fantastic.  (And technically, hearing something twice isn't an accessibility issue, or at least it's not a WCAG issue.)

I like that you keep the focus on the date that was selected when it's in a different month.

One possible way to fix the issue, and this is pretty convoluted, is to make the new date object hidden from the screen reader temporarily.  Set `aria-hidden="true"` on the element but then you'd need a timer to remove the `aria-hidden` attribute after the page had sufficient time for the screen reader to honor the hidden attribute.